# meteor.js cant find module is-property when attempting to run cordova

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWcoH.png)

I receive the error displayed above. I attempted into a different computer and it worked just fine. I have meteor,npm, is-property, and node installed and working properly. I have tried to manually install is-property many times.I have also tried to reinstall all the components but the module is-property still won't get detected from my computer. I run a windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

locate this directory in your pc and

*C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\is-my-json-valid*

Then run:

```
meteor npm install is-property
```

[source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7358)

Answer (score 0):

What i did was :

1- go to this path:

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\is-my-json-valid\node_modules
```

2- the copy the path

3 - write this command :

```
subst x: C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\is-my-json-valid\node_modules
```

4- then I went to x:

5 - after that i was in my x i navigate to `generate-object-property`

6- in that folder run

```
npm install is-property
```

after that you can run your command in your project folder you should be fine